# Electron error "is not a function" when using a function from a different JS file

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to create my first electron app.

I have a function in a JavaScript file (OtherFile.js):

```
function initializeOther() {
 ...
}
```

In my main JavaScript file I have

```
const { initializeOther} = require('./ioadapters/controllers/OtherFile');

function main() {
  initializeOther();
  app.on('ready', createWindow);
}

...

main();
```

I am trying to use the function from the other file. I only defined the function. I am not "exporting" it.

But I am getting following error:

App threw an error during load
TypeError: initializeOther is not a function

What do I have to do to fix it?

Comment: How are you exporting `initializeOther`?

Comment: where do you export initializeOther?